# Event Hub Trigger Azure Function Not Being Triggered When Using Non-Default Consumer Group

Tags: azure, azure-functions, azure-eventhub

So I have a basic setup for listening on events coming in to Event Hub, using an Event Hub Trigger function, defined as follows:

```
[FunctionName("myfunction")]
public async Run([EventHubTrigger(myeventhub, Connection = "EventHubConnectionAppSetting", ConsumerGroup = %myconsumergroup%)], EventData eventHubMessage, ILogger logger)
```

Where the values for the connection and consumergroup parameters are in my local settings.

Running my function and sending events via Postman (properly authenticated), the function is not triggered.

The only way the function is every triggered is if I remove the ConsumerGroup from the parameters, which will cause it to point to the $Default consumer group for the event hub:

```
[FunctionName("myfunction")]
public async Run([EventHubTrigger(myeventhub, Connection = "EventHubConnectionAppSetting"], EventData eventHubMessage, ILogger logger)
```

My goal is to keep my custom consumer group and have the function trigger for events coming into that consumer group.

I will mention that I'm testing this out locally, and using local storage:

```
AzureWebJobsStorage="UseDevelopmentStorage=true"
```

But obviously the event hub in question is an actual created resource on Azure, with the relevant consumer group existing under it as well.

Comment: Does is work if you provide a static consumer group name instead of %myconsumergroup%?

Comment: @SerkantKaraca No, it does not

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can directly use the consumer group name in the function, like below:

```
[FunctionName("myfunction")]
public async Run([EventHubTrigger(myeventhub, Connection = "EventHubConnectionAppSetting", ConsumerGroup = "myconsumergroup_name")], EventData eventHubMessage, ILogger logger)
```

**Or** if you want to use this mode `%myconsumergroup%`, you can refer to this steps as below:

In local.settings.json(remember right click the file -> select properties -> set "Copy to Output Directory" as "copy if newer"), define the key-values like below:

```
{
    "IsEncrypted": false,
  "Values": {
    "AzureWebJobsStorage": "UseDevelopmentStorage=true",
    "FUNCTIONS_WORKER_RUNTIME": "dotnet",
    "EventHubConnectionAppSetting": "xxxx",
    "EventHubConsumerGroup": "your_consumergroup_name"
  }
}
```

then in the function method, define the function like below:

```
    [FunctionName("Function1")]
    public static async Task Run([EventHubTrigger("eventhub_name", Connection = "EventHubConnectionAppSetting",ConsumerGroup = "%EventHubConsumerGroup%")] EventData[] events, ILogger log)
```

Note: I use the latest packages for the function.

Comment: this is exactly what was done in the question, local settings contained the EventHubConsumerGroup property, with it's corresponding value, that I confirmed exists in the relevant event hub, but it doesn't work. It causes the function to not trigger.

Comment: @mkcoding, there're many things you need to check. 1: make sure the consumer group is the one created for the eventhub used in your azure function. 2: or you can create a new consumer group, then use the new one to test. 3. update the packages to latest ones in your function. 4. If possible, you can use a azure storage account instead of the local one, to make sure no error from eventhub. 5. please update the local storage to the latest one.

Comment: If you still have the issue, please show us your completed code/config file. Or I can share the working code at my side to you.

Comment: oddly enough using a separate event hub namespace (with the same event hub name and consumer group name) triggered the function.